# Make select method after FindAsync() method?

Tags: entity-framework

I use entity framework 6.
I use FindAsync() extension to retrieve record from database:

```
 protected readonly DbSet<T> Table
 return await Table.FindAsync(id);
```

How can I make select on this `Table.FindAsync(id)` row to retrieve specific records from retrieved row?

Comment: *specific records* means some of properties? Why not use `Table.Where(m => m.Id == id).Select(.......).First();`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *specific records*, or why you would need another select after you've just fetched a whole row. Can you illustrate what you are after with an example?

Comment: @AdilMammadov, yes some properties or some fields

Comment: @Michael, Is there any reason to not use `Table.Where(m => m.Id == id).Select(.......).First();`?

Comment: @ yes I use repository pattern.And Table.FindAsync() is implemented in my code

Comment: @Michael, you can always change your code :). Personally, my repositories exposes `IQueryable<T>` so I can query what I want. If you do not want to change your Repositories, then yo will need to create new anonymous type and return it instead. like: `protected readonly DbSet<T> Table
var findResult = await Table.FindAsync(id);
var result = new { findResult.Id, findResult.Name };
return result;`